# Package imakeidx not printing index voices/items into the Index chapter

Tags: babel, indexing, imakeidx

Good evening everyone.
I have a problem with the package imakeidx, coding on Overleaf (XeTeX engine, TeX Live 2021) a master's thesis. This is an example of my main.tex document, which produces the problem I will describe.

```
       \documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  oneside,
  openright]{book}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[intoc]
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.5cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} 
\usepackage[fontsize=12pt]{scrextend} 
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[arabic,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{morewrites}
\setRlineflag{}
\pagestyle{plain}


\begin{document}

\title{Test}
\author{G.A.}
\date{}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Example}
Example\index{example} text. Example text. Example text.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

First of all, imakeidx only actually prints the index page if given the option `xindy`. It also regularly appears in the table of contents.
Problem is, it does not print any index voice. I checked the imakeidx documentation, and could not solve this problem.
For example, when I write:

```
Example\index{Example} text
```

in the body of my document, it does not appear in the Index. I checked the output files, and this is what I have found.
ILG file says:

```
    !! Input index error (file = output.idx, line = 1):
   -- Illegal space within numerals in second argument.
```

And the IDX file says:

```
\indexentry{Example}{\if@rlmain \I {12}\else \textLR {12}\fi }
```

I have tried to add the `noautomatic` option in the preamble as well. All it does is not printing the Index at all.

Comment: possibly urelated but never use either `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` or `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with xetex

Comment: please fix your example so that people can run it to see the problem and test answers. Currently it jus shows a list of probably unrelated packages, and no example of an index entry that goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the inputenc/fontenc suggestion. I tried, but it did not work. I modified the main question.

Comment: that was unrelated to your qustion (but you had not posted an example that was related, so I commented on what I could see)  (the updated file still has `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`)

Comment: I can simplify your example to `\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[arabic]{babel}
\begin{document}
\end{document}` and still get an inputenc error

Comment: If I remove `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` Overleaf returns a fatal error and stops compiling. If I only remove the `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` no problem is shown.
In any case, `imakeidx` does not work.

Comment: yes but the inputenc issue is a sign that the babel arabic file isn't set up for xetex, if you can make an example witthout all the unrelated packages, you could raise an issue at the babel github, but I added babel tag, perhaps Javier will pass by and comment.

Comment: Thanks for the moment. I will keep investigating in the meantime.